# When do covering spaces correspond to characteristic subgroups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, covering-spaces

Given a covering space $p \colon X \to Y$, we get an injection $p^* \colon \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$, and we know that the image $p^*(\pi_1(X))$ is normal in $\pi_1(Y)$ if an only if $p$ is *regular*, that is if the deck group of the covering $p$ acts transitively on preimages of points in $Y$. This is a satisfyingly topological criterion for a group-theoretic property.

Is a similarly topological criterion possible for the case where $p^*(\pi_1(X))$ is not just normal in $\pi_1(Y)$ but characteristic?

Edit: If it helps, $X$ can be assumed to be aspherical. The initial context in which this came up was surfaces.

Comment: Given that automorphisms of $\pi_1(Y)$ do not necessarily come from automorphisms of $Y$, I don't think there's a sensible answer to this.

Comment: You could however make sense of it for $K(\pi,1)$ spaces.

Comment: @RyanBudney my use case is (infinite-type, orientable) surfaces, so everything is helpfully aspherical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a $K(\pi,1)$. Then by definition every endomorphism, hence every automorphism $f_\star\colon \pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1(X,x)$ may be realized by a continuous map $f\colon (X,x) \to (X,x)$.

If $p\colon (\tilde X,\tilde x) \to (X,x)$ is a covering map such that $p_\star(\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x))$ is characteristic in $\pi_1(X,x)$, then every homotopy equivalence $f\colon (X,x) \to (X,x)$ preserves the image $p_\star(\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x))$ so by the lifting criterion (see Hatcher chapter 1, for example), there exists a lift $\tilde f\colon (\tilde X,\tilde x) \to (\tilde X,\tilde x)$ such that $p\tilde f = fp$. In fact, if every homotopy equivalence lifts to $\tilde X$, then the converse of my use of the lifting criterion implies that $p_\star(\pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x))$ is characteristic in $\pi_1(X,x)$.

Comment: Will not actually self-homeomorphisms suffice? I mean, if you follow some classifying space functor construction, I believe you end up with a bijective self-map...

Comment: Definitely not. For example, if $X$ is a graph and $\pi_1(X)$ is a free group, then any homeomorphism of $X$ must preserve the "natural" cell structure on the graph (that is, it must send vertices of valence at least three to vertices of the same valence because they are topologically distinguished, so it must send edges of this cell structure to edges). Thus a homeomorphism of a graph is homotopic to a graph automorphism, which thus, if $X$ is a finite graph, has finite order.